# Is it possible to publish Access 2010 Templates to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, access

Access 2010 has [some wonderful templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/templates/CT010214400.aspx). So, I was planning to use one of those on my SP2010 site. But before starting I have some questions:

1. When an Access 2010 templates is published in Sharepoint 2010 site, where is database stored & can it be accessed by our coders? Can I have a SQL database as back-end for data of these published templates
2. Are there any other ways of syncing database with an external source. If yes, what are the requirements of the external source?

Any tutorial or links would be of great help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL as a backend, you can use the data from there as External Content Types out of the box and the data will remain in that location and be displayed as lists within your site. These lists can be used just like any other list in SharePoint, you can create, read, update or delete the items in the list if you create them with the appropriate operations. There are also several cool things you can do with Access Services in 2010. There are several posts about it and what you can do with it here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/tags/2010+intro+series/default.aspx.